# Parsing an XML with unknown and variable tags into a readable format

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have an XML of a webpage which has varying formats and nested tables.I am not able to parse the XML to give readable outputs.

I was trying to use the ElementTree library to accomplish the task, but I haven't been able to make any progress in getting a readable and well formatted result.
The XML looks something like this :

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/universal_parse.xsl"?><AgentXmppConnectionStatus type="sandesh"><peer identifier="1" type="list"><list size="1" type="struct"><AgentXmppData><controller_ip identifi
er="1" type="string">192.168.100.2</controller_ip><state identifier="2" type="string">Established</state><peer_name identifier="3"> <peer_addres
s identifier="4" type="string">192.168.100.2:5269</peer_address><cfg_controller identifier="5" type="string">Yes</cfg_controller><mcast_controller identifier="6" type="string">Yes</mcast_controller><last_
state identifier="7" type="string">
```

The actual webpage has results in formats similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwugg.png) and also other varying formats.
So I am looking for a Python script which takes in the XML and gives the output in a format which readable and similar to how it actually appears on the webpage.

(PS:This is the first time I am asking a question Stack Overflow, so kindly excuse any mistakes from my side)

Comment: Hare Srinivasa. If you need a code beautifier, you can get it online like : https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer. If you want a xml renderer, you need to have a good css file. I am not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: Your xml is invalid.

Comment: The term "readable" is subjective. If you want to handle any arbitrary XML, it's going to be difficult to devise a display format that is any more readable than XML itself. If you think you can devise a format that is more readable than lexical XML, then let us know what it is, and we can help you generate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this XML with BeautifulSoup. This could give you an idea:

```
data = '''<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/universal_parse.xsl"?><AgentXmppConnectionStatus type="sandesh"><peer identifier="1" type="list"><list size="1" type="struct"><AgentXmppData><controller_ip identifi
er="1" type="string">192.168.100.2</controller_ip><state identifier="2" type="string">Established</state><peer_name identifier="3"> <peer_addres
s identifier="4" type="string">192.168.100.2:5269</peer_address><cfg_controller identifier="5" type="string">Yes</cfg_controller><mcast_controller identifier="6" type="string">Yes</mcast_controller><last_
state identifier="7" type="string">'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print('{: <20}{}'.format('cfg_controller:', soup.select_one('agentxmppconnectionstatus ~ cfg_controller').text))
print('{: <20}{}'.format('mcast_controller:', soup.select_one('agentxmppconnectionstatus ~ mcast_controller').text))
print()
print('{: <20}{: <20}{: <20}'.format('controller_ip', 'state', 'peer_name'))
for row in zip(soup.select('peer agentxmppdata controller_ip'),
               soup.select('peer agentxmppdata state'),
               soup.select('peer agentxmppdata peer_name')):
    print('{: <20}{: <20}{: <20}'.format(*[d.text.strip() for d in row]))

# print(soup.prettify())  <--- uncomment this line for pretty print the whole XML
```

Prints:

```
cfg_controller:     Yes
mcast_controller:   Yes

controller_ip       state               peer_name           
192.168.100.2       Established         192.168.100.2:5269
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, but the problem is I don't know the tags before hand.I get different xml with varying tags each time and the script should be able to parse any xml that it gets. Atleast if not the exact format , it should be able to display all values that come under a particular heading(in the sense it should properly identify and display the parent and child relationship).